# Display full-color unicode glyphs in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode

I am trying to figure out why in `gnome-terminal` (or other terminals, like `Konsole`, and `terminator`), unicode glyphs are shown as outlines; where as on iTerm on OSX, they are shown as full-color images.

Here is a graphic to illustrate what I am talking about. This is the same zsh theme, with the same font, running on iTerm and gnome-terminal:

[image]

[image]

How can I enable the full-color glyphs on the Linux terminal?

Comment: Apple has their own proprietary font extension for bitmap glyphs, which I don't believe is supported anywhere else. Google has one too, as does Mozilla+Adobe, and Microsoft, and there's a combined chimerical one coming out of MPEG sometime soon. I don't *think* you can get any of these going in any currently-existing Linux terminal, although Mozilla has a patch they apply to their copy of FreeType that might be able to be adapted, as does Google. Terminals are still harder to fix after that. I think it's impractical at this point, though I'd be interested in any answers someone comes up with.